# "No explicit conversion of Symbol into String" for new records in rails 4.0.1 (only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

After my rails 4 upgrade, trying to create a new record for any of my ActiveRecord classes gives

```
No explicit conversion of Symbol into String
```

For example, here is my links links_params method

```
def link_params
  params.require(:link)
  .permit(:url_address, :group_id, :alt_text, :version_number, 
  :position, :content_date, :verified_date) # This is line 157
end

# line 118 is: @link = Link.new(link_params)
```

but I get

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):
  app/controllers/links_controller.rb:157:in `link_params'
  app/controllers/links_controller.rb:118:in `create'

This error occurred while loading the following files:
link

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"0FqFTx2EjCIO+R+rm97lF15+id4b452n+dBuUNxAL9U=",
 "link"=>{"url_address"=>"http://www.google.com",
 "alt_text"=>"",
 "version_number"=>"",
 "group_id"=>"49",
 "content_date"=>"08/18/2014"},
 "commit"=>"Save"}
```

Comment: Weird. What's the output of `params.class`?

Comment: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure how it happened, but it looks like your params object is just a hash... and not an `ActionController::Parameters` object.  When params is just a hash:

```
params = {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0FqFTx2EjCIO+R+rm97lF15+id4b452n+dBuUNxAL9U=", "link"=>{"url_address"=>"http://www.google.com", "alt_text"=>"", "version_number"=>"", "group_id"=>"49", "content_date"=>"08/18/2014"}, "commit"=>"Save"}

params.require(:link)
=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

params.class
=> Hash
```

But if it's an ActionController::Parameters object

```
params2 = ActionController::Parameters.new({"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0FqFTx2EjCIO+R+rm97lF15+id4b452n+dBuUNxAL9U=", "link"=>{"url_address"=>"http://www.google.com", "alt_text"=>"", "version_number"=>"", "group_id"=>"49", "content_date"=>"08/18/2014"}, "commit"=>"Save"})

params2.require(:link)
=>{"url_address"=>"http://www.google.com", "alt_text"=>"", "version_number"=>"", "group_id"=>"49", "content_date"=>"08/18/2014"} 

params2.class
=>ActionController::Parameters
```

Are you doing something to `params` before `link_params` gets a hold of it?

EDIT:
According to the [API Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters), Strong params is only available in Rails 4.0.2.  If you're using an earlier version, you will have to stick with Rails 3 attr_accessible

Comment: I mean, you could always put `params = ActionController::Parameters.new(params)` just before you filter it. But it's really weird that you aren't being served this object already....

Comment: Is your version of Rails > 4.0.2?

Comment: Ah, and rails 4.0.2 fixes it!  Care to post that as an answer?  Can just update this one I guess.

Comment: Your comment doing `params = ActionController::Parameters.new(params)` doesn't work in Rails 3 since the class is not available yet.