# "no implicit conversion of Symbol into String" when trying to create a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into String` when I try to create a new record, which I don't understand because all data is formed of strings.

In the controller I have:

```
def new
    @account = Account.new
end

def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
end

private
    def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:username, :firstname, :lastname, :organisation, :phonenumber, :avatar, :about, :verified)
end
```

And the form is simply:

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
  <div>
   <%= f.label :username %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div>
   <%= f.label :firstname %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </div>
  <div>
   <%= f.label :lastname %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>
  ... more of the same...

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the migration file:

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|

      t.string   :username
      t.string   :firstname
      t.string   :lastname
      t.string   :organisation
      ...more of the same, all strings...
    end
  add_index :accounts, :username,                unique: true
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have been a bit unclear. 
First, I mistakenly thought I was using Ruby 4 but ```ruby -v``` tells me that it's version 2.1.5. that I'm using. Sorry about that.  
Second, my question is what am I doing wrong? What is causing the error ```no implicit conversion of Symbol into String``` when I try to create a new record via http://localhost:3000/accounts/new/?

Comment: probably this issue is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374559/no-explicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-string-for-new-records-in-rails-4

Comment: I've read the different posts on this error message but unfortunately without a solution. By the way, the full error message is: 
```TypeError in AccountsController#create ```
```no implicit conversion of Symbol into String  ```

```app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:59:in `account_params' ```
```app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:17:in `create'  ```

```This error occurred while loading the following files: account```

Comment: Also updating to rails 3.2.21 has not worked (no difference). Any suggestions what else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3.2 doesn't include strong parameters.  If you want to use them, you need to add the gem 'strong_parameters' to your Gemfile.

This stack overflow answer talks about the necessary steps.

[Strong Parameters in Rails 3.2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852534/strong-parameters-in-rails-3-2-8)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:
In the controller I had to change

```
@account = Account.new(account_params)
```

to

```
@account = Account.new(params[:account])
```

Comment: Or install the strong parameters as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Or migrate to Rails 4.